# Windows 10 Desktop Bridge: DRM

Tags: uwp, drm, desktop-bridge

I have created a UWP app for Windows 10 using the Desktop Bridge. However, after install the package, the exe file can be copied from `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`, and it can run on other PCs, is there any way about copy protection just like Steam DRM?

I want to prevent the exe file from running outside of Windows Store, is there any easy way to implement it? The desktop converter can do it ? Or any window store API can be used?

Comment: This is true for all .NET assemblies that are deployed on the client. But if some one is good enough to reverse engineer the app, he is very likely able to write one from scratch. And I don't think the files copied from that folder can be used on other PCs without going thru the process of decompile - recompile - repackage - deploy.

Comment: the copied files is .exe file, it can be used on other PCs directly.

Comment: Oh. Then this question is actually about protecting the desktop exe. And I believe there are many _old_ posts on stackoverflow about this topic. Can you provide more context? be specific about your requirement.

Comment: I want to prevent my app from running outside of windows store, is there any easy way to implement it? The desktop convert can do it ? Or any window store api can be used? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following API to check at runtime if the app instance has a valid store license:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense.skustoreid

If the user has installed the app from the Microsoft Store it will have a SkuStoreId, other it will have none. This check can also be performed when offline.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I published my product to the store, the product is not free and i download it with a promotion code, then copy to another pc which has never installed this product before, but StoreAppLicense.IsActive always return true. Why it doesn't work? Can i use StoreAppLicense.IsActive to check if current user has entitlement to use this app in this case?

Comment: Sorry, turns out my understanding of IsActive was wrong. I checked with the team and the correct thing to check for is the SkuStoreId. In the unlicensed case it won't exist. I'll update my answer when I get back to my keyboard.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense.skustoreid

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. I have another question, does it require the internet when using Windows.Services.Store APIs? If there is no internet, can we get the storeAPPLicense and the SkuStoreId?

Comment: The API should work offline as well. Should be easy enough to test out. Let us know if you run into any issues.